# CheckBox with onTouchListener

Tags: android, checkbox, ontouchlistener

I have a `checkbox` with `onTouchListener`, and in this listener, I have switch with these cases:

- `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`
- `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`
- `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL`

When I don't have `view.performClick()` in the `ACTION_UP` case, I get a lint warning:

> onTouch should call View#performClick when a click is detected

But it causes my method to not work:

```
public void touchCheckBox(View view) {
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    checkBox.performClick();
}
```

My method works fine if I add `view.performClick()` in ACTION_DOWN too.

My code for `touchCheckBox()` is:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    boolean isEventConsumed;
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            row.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blueSelection));
            isEventConsumed = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            view.performClick();
            row.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            touchCheckBox(row);
            isEventConsumed = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            row.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            isEventConsumed = true;
            break;
        default:
            isEventConsumed = false;
            break;
    }
    return isEventConsumed;
}
```

});

Is `view.performClick()` necessary in the `ACTION_UP` case, or I can suppress the lint warning?

Answer (score 2):

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1394

It was reported as bug, I think you just surpress the warning.

Well, try this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // stuffs
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        v.performClick();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: but in that case there is return fals always and in my case i return true in MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN MotionEvent.ACTION_UP and in MotionEvent.ACTION_UP I call touchCheckBox() method.

Comment: This is a similar code to my. Look on my edited post.